# What are the three green wires on the back of my dryer for?

Tags: dryer

On the back of my Maytag model MED5800TWO clothes dryer, what do the three green, I believe they are ground wires, connect to on the back electrical panel of dryer?

Not the itself but the upper panel containing the wiring system.  Two of the green ground wires are both connected to a small bolted screw but the third one is not connected to anything and hanging loose.

Atchison time my dryer will not start. When you turn the timer knob you can hear the motor but when you push the start button it does not kick on.

Comment: A photo might help; I'm not sure why there would be multiple green wires.

Answer (score 0):

Your dryer should be wired in a very similar fashion to the one in the Q&A [Short circuit in dryer?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101206/short-circuit-in-dryer)

The green wires are almost certainly ground connections. As for the dryer not starting, there are a few possibilities. Take a quick look at the door switch to make sure the arm that the door pushes when it closes in not broken off.There is a thermal fuse inside the back of the dryer with 2 light blue wires plugged in, that is the first strong possibility you would want to check! If that fuse is open it is bad and you will want to check the home duct for a blockage.  If that's not it, next is the door switch (this time you will need to check it with a multimeter for continuity, it's normally open) Then the timer... your dryer has a very reliable timer style so I doubt that! The start switch is very rare to fail also, and lastly the motor or a loose connection somewhere.